# Change URL But Don't Go There jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, url

How do I change the current URL with jQuery without reloading the page (to add parameters) so that I can use $_GET[''] in PHP.

Basically, I have a form and I want the user inputs to go to the URL as parameters instead of using the usual $_POST['']. I don't want to use post because I want it to work if the user reloads the page or goes to another page then goes back to this page.

I don't want to reload the page because I have some ajax stuff going on for animations and a reload would interfere with that.

Comment: You should look into HTML 5 PushState https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history

Comment: How are you planning to get your request variables to PHP if you don't make a request?

Comment: Please explain in brief what do you want to do

Answer (score 1):

somebody had made a plugin named [jquery-pjax](https://github.com/defunkt/jquery-pjax)
or pure javascript [pjax](https://github.com/welefen/pjax)

Answer (score 0):

There's option `history.pushState('', 'Title', newHREF);`
but i don't think you can use $_GET[] after change the url.

[Modify the URL without reloading the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page)